Objectify load entity by id fails inconsistently
I am trying to load an entity from datastore by :
objectifyFactory.ofy().load().type(clazz).id(id).now();
However, this returns a null, even though the entity is present in the datastore. In another function, this runs just fine. I don't understand what might be causing this inconsistent behaviour.
Details:
Function 1:
public String addEntity(VaultEntry vaultEntry, Class<? extends VaultEntry> clazz) {
    return doWorkWithObjectify(() -> objectifyFactory.ofy().transact(() -> {

      // Check if the entity already exists
      VaultEntry alreadyExistingEntry =
          objectifyFactory.ofy().load().type(clazz).id(vaultEntry.getId()).now();  
     // <--- This returns the existing entity just fine. No issues here.

Function 2:
public VaultEntry getEntityById(String id, Class<? extends VaultEntry> clazz) {
    return doWorkWithObjectify(() -> {
      VaultEntry alreadyExistingEntry = objectifyFactory.ofy().load().type(clazz).id(id).now();
    // <---- This returns a null.

My DAO looks like this:
VaultEntry is an interface. SimpleVaultEntry is an implementation of this interface, with fields "id" which is annotated with @Id and "referenceKey" which is annotated with @Index. SimpleVaultEntry is tagged with @Entity.
I am not using the ObjectifyService but directly working with ObjectifyFactory object. This is because I have multiple ObjectifyFactory objects connecting with different datastores at the same time.
In the above 2 functions, I have verified that objectifyFactory object is same in both the functions, however objectifyFactory.ofy() object is different (which is expected since Objectify object is local to a thread).
What might be causing this issue? What other info can I provide to help debug this further?
Thanks.
